# Generate flatbuffers windows shared lib with CMake

Tags: cmake, flatbuffers

I am trying to generate Windows shared lib (dll) of Google flatbuffers (https://github.com/google/flatbuffers) using CMake.
I have used the following `cmake` command, but it always generates a static library (*.lib) when I build it.

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
```

I also tried the options `CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_SUFFIX` and 
 `CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` with CMake. Unfortunately it always generates a *.lib

What do I need to do to generate *.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Flatbuffers CMake code, there is a CMake option `FLATBUFFERS_BUILD_SHAREDLIB` [here](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/14baf45c90a076d405e75cfc41874ffff862fb72/CMakeLists.txt#L20):

```
option(FLATBUFFERS_BUILD_SHAREDLIB
       "Enable the build of the flatbuffers shared library"
       OFF)
```

You can set this option when you call CMake to enable the **shared** library build:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DFLATBUFFERS_BUILD_SHAREDLIB=ON
```

---

For future reference, you can list all of the cached CMake variables using:

```
cmake -LH
```

This will show all of the defined `FLATBUFFERS_*` options you can configure for the build.

Comment: `cmake -LH` is the key and need to be run with the `-S` flag so that it doesn't pollute the root directory. Thanks for pointing it out.